# Flutter Unity Widget Firebase deploy firebaseapp.com working but web.app not

Tags: flutter, unity-webgl

I am currently developing a flutter app which uses the unity flutter widget.
It always worked perfectly when using deploy firebase, but somehow not it does not upload the folder anymore, just a UnityLibrary file.
I was trying everything without any success. Then i realised there are 2 different hosting sites when using deploy firebase command. 1 is the normal name.web.app url, the other is the name.firebaseapp.com. Somehow the firebaseapp.com one works normal and the web.app not(see screenshot). Can someone find out what could be wrong? I already contacted the support for this a few days ago, but no one responded.

[image: Left firebaseapp.com, right web.app]

Answer (score 0):

Ok contacting firebase support fixed the problem, now it is working again